# Вывод наиболее отдаленных от корня дерева элементов (СИ)

Tags: c, бинарное-дерево

По-немногу разбираюсь со структурными данными, сейчас вопрос к деревьям. Есть задача: вывести элементы, наиболее отдаленные от корня дерева. 
Есть вполне рабочий код-основание, и совсем неверно рабочая функция *Last_Print*...
Её логику сама до конца не обьясню - как слепой котенок писала, на интуицию.

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать что-то адекватное

```c
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct tree {
    int  key;
    char s[100];
    struct tree* left;
    struct tree* right;
} Tree;
int  Tree_Add(Tree** tr, int key, const char* s);
void Tree_Clear(Tree* tr);
unsigned int Tree_Height(const Tree* tr);
void Tree_Print(const Tree* tr, int level);
void Last_Print(const Tree* tr, const int start_level, int level, const int height);

int main(void) {
    Tree* tr = NULL;

    Tree_Add(&tr, 32, "Apple");
    Tree_Add(&tr, 26, "Samsung");
    Tree_Add(&tr, 64, "Lenovo");
    Tree_Add(&tr, 16, "Xiaomi");
    Tree_Add(&tr, 48, "Meizu");
    Tree_Add(&tr, 53, "Nokia");
    Tree_Add(&tr, 88, "Huawei");
    Tree_Add(&tr, 30, "LG");
    Tree_Add(&tr, 40, "Sony");
    Tree_Print(tr, 0);
    int h = Tree_Height(tr);
    printf("height tree: %d\n", h);
    Last_Print(tr, 1, 1, h);
    Tree_Clear(tr);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

//вставка
int Tree_Add(Tree** tr, int key, const char* s) {
    Tree* p = *tr;
    while (p != NULL) {
        if (key < p->key) {
            tr = &p->left;
            p = p->left;
        }
        else if (key > p->key) {
            tr = &p->right;
            p = p->right;
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }
    p = (Tree*)malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    if (p != NULL) {
        p->left = p->right = NULL;
        p->key = key;
        strcpy(p->s, s);
        *tr = p;
    }
    return (p != NULL);
}

//видалення всіх
void Tree_Clear(Tree* tr) {
    if (tr != NULL) {
        if (tr->left != NULL)
            Tree_Clear(tr->left);
        if (tr->right != NULL)
            Tree_Clear(tr->right);
        free(tr);
    }
}

//висота дерева
unsigned int Tree_Height(const Tree* tr) {
    unsigned int l, r;
    if (tr != NULL) {
        l = (tr->left != NULL) ? Tree_Height(tr->left) : 0;
        r = (tr->right != NULL) ? Tree_Height(tr->right) : 0;
        return ((l > r) ? l : r) + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

//вивід усього дерева
void Tree_Print(const Tree* tr, int level)
{
    if (tr)
    {
        Tree_Print(tr->left, level + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) printf("              ");
        printf("%d (%s)\n", tr->key, tr->s);
        Tree_Print(tr->right, level + 1);
    }
}

//вивід найнижчого рівня
void Last_Print(const Tree* tr, const int start_level, int level, const int height)
{
    if (tr)
    {
        Last_Print(tr->left, start_level, level + 1, height);
        if (level = start_level + height - 2)
        {
            printf("%d (%s)\n", tr->key, tr->s);
        }
        Last_Print(tr->right, start_level, level + 1, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: Нужно вывести листья или только элементы с наибольшей глубиной?

Comment: Только элементы с наибольшей глубиной

Answer (score 1, accepted):

функция реализуется по подобию функции Tree_Height, только в неё передаём уже рассчитанную глубину дерева, чтобы сравнивать, достигли мы её или нет:

```
unsigned int Last_Print(const Tree* tr,  const unsigned int height) {
    unsigned int l, r;
    if (tr != NULL) {
        l = (tr->left != NULL) ? Last_Print(tr->left) : 0;
        r = (tr->right != NULL) ? Last_Print(tr->right) : 0;
        const unsigned int current_height = ((l > r) ? l : r) + 1;

        if(current_height == height)
        {
            printf("%d (%s)\n", tr->key, tr->s);
        }

        return current_height;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

соответственно в main() делаем такой вызов:

```
int h = Tree_Height(tr);
printf("height tree: %d\n", h);
Last_Print(tr, h);
```